# Find the p.d.f of Z = X+Y given a joint pdf

Tags: density-function

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables for which the joint
p.d.f. is as follows:

$f (x, y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 2(x+y) && &0\le x\le y \le 1\\ 
 0&& &elsewhere
\end{matrix}\right.$

Find the p.d.f. of $Z = X + Y $.

I am confused as to how the answer for the bounds changes from  $ 0 \le z-t \le t \le 1$ to $ z/2 \le t \le z$.

Answer:

> However, the integrand is positive only for $0 \le z-t \le t \le 1$. Therefore, for $0 \le z \le 1$, it is positive only for $z/2 \le t\le z$.
>
> $$g(z)= \int_{z/2}^z 2z dt = z^2$$
>
> For $1 < z <2$, the inegrand is positive only for $ z/2 \le t \le 1$ and we have
>
> $$ g(z) =\int_z^22z dt = z(2-z)$$

Comment: What happens when you solve $0 \le z-t \le t \le 1$ for $t$ in terms of $z$?

Comment: I'm not sure how to start...but I tried and got z <= 2t ? so z/2 = t?

Comment: There you go--that's half of it!

Comment: how would I get the other side? It's a little confusing

Answer (score 1):

> I am confused as to how the answer for the bounds changes from  $ 0 \le z-t \le t  \le 1$ to $ z/2 \le t \le z$.

They are all from $ 0 \le z-t \le t \le 1$

$z-t \le t \Rightarrow z\le 2t \Rightarrow z/2 \le t \tag{1}$

Form $ 0 \le z-t \Rightarrow t \le z \tag{2}$

Combine (1) and (2) you get $z/2 \le t \le z$

This is answer for your confusion but not for the problem.